# Angularjs: Can i have one route with multiple views?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Consider a certain route let's say **myapp\profile**
which has two modes (buyer/seller)
What i would like to achieve is:

- keep the same route url for both modes
- Alternate the view with different HTML files (lets say buyer.html, seller.html), of course each view has it's view model.
- Sharing some logic between the two modes.
- I would like to have a controller/logic to each mode

What i already considered:

1. Thought about using **ui-router's sub states**, but I dont want to change the url.
2. Thought about creating this 'profile' route and while navigating to it, figure the mode (buyer/seller), and then $state.go to a new state (but again, i would like to keep same route name at the end so it's not ok)
3. Ideally thought i could navigate to my shared controller and then render the correct view and controller, but this idea kinda messed up me.

Could you share what is a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### most use cases

Normally, in order to dynamically select a template for a state, you can use a function:

```
state = {
    .....
    templateUrl: function($stateParams){
         if ($stateParams.isThis === true)
             return 'this.html'
         else
             return 'that.html'
    }
}
```

### but...

Unfortunately you can't pass other injectables to the templateUrl function.  UI.Router only passes `$stateParams`.  You don't want to alter the URL in anyway so you can't use this.

### when you need to inject more than $stateParams

But you can leverage `templateProvider` instead. With this feature, you can pass a service to your `templateProvider` function to determine if your user is a *buyer* or *seller*.  You'll also want to use UI.Router's `$templateFactory` service to easily pull and cache your template.

```
state = {
    ....
    templateProvider: function($templateFactory, profileService){
        var url = profileService.isBuyer ? 'buyer.html' : 'seller.html';
        return $templateFactory.fromUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Here it is working in your plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/0gLBJlQrNPUNtkqWNrZm?p=preview

Docs:

- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates
- [http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$templateFactory](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$templateFactor)

Comment: It sounded interesting untill u mention showing and hiding different values, which means i can't really hold two different templates for each mode.
I don't want one manipulated template, it makes things messy.

Comment: I updated it to reflect using different templates based on the $stateParams

Comment: wow, first i didn't know u can handle the template url dynamiclly!
But i'll challenge this idea, i am guessing i could have userService (as an example) instead of having $stateParams right?

Comment: I'm guessing you could, I'm not entirely sure though as I haven't needed this functionality in my own app.

Comment: I just dont want to have a different url other than "myapp/profile", trying to figure the meaning of the data added to url as u showed.

Comment: There are restrictions on what can be injected, but generally those are during the execution of Angular's configuration phase.

Comment: Yeah, the state definition is the configuration phase.

Comment: right, but that function should be getting called during the *run* phase of the app, I don't understand why you'd have run-phase injectables not be able to be injected at this phase of the game.  You might try using the `resolve` attribute for your state.  THough I don't know if a race condition will exist in which the template function executes before the resolved items.  If you set up a plunkr/jsfiddle, I can help you out.

Comment: I just tested this on my app and you can in fact pass *run-phase* injectables into your templateUrl function.  That being the case, I am going to update the answer to reflect what we've discussed here.  If you require further help for trying to get your UserService into the templateUrl Function, we can work on that separately.

Comment: Well im trying to set a plnkr, but struggling erm..
Regarding accessing the run injectables, could u clarify how? Consider the fact im in a config function when registering the route itself. Btw, i don't think the resolve step would be helpful here, it's too late to handle the template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101728/discussion-between-jusopi-and-popokoko).